# A SQL query to work on a table with subgroups

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a large Oracle DB table which contains nearly 200 millions of rows. It has only three columns: A subscriber id field, a date field and an offer id field.

For each row in this table, I need to find whether this row has any corresponding rows in the table such that:

**1)** They belong to the same subscriber (same subscriber id)

**2)** They are from a certain distance in the past from the current row (for example if our current row is A, the row B with the same subscriber id should have that A.date > B.date >= A.date - 30(days))

**3)** In addition to 2) we will have to query for a specific offer id as well: (A.date > B.date >= A.date - 30 and B.offerid == some_id)

I am aware of the Oracle Analytics functions lag and lead and I plan to use them for this purpose. These function returns value of the fields above or below of the current row on the ordered table, according to some given fields. The disturbing thing is that the number of rows with the same subscriber id field varies up to 84. When I use an ORDER BY statement on (SUBSCRIBER_ID,DATE) with lag function, then for each row, I need to check 84 rows above of the current one, in order to make sure that the rows above share the same SUBSCRIBER_ID with my current row. Since some subscriber id subgroups only have entries around of 3 - 4 rows, this amount of unnecessary row accesses is wasteful.

How can I accomplish this job, without being in need to check 84 rows each time, for each row? Does Oracle support any methods which work solely on subgroups generated by the GROUP BY statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the analytic function COUNT(*) in Oracle did the necessary stuff for me. I used the following structure

```
SELECT
SUBSCRIBER_ID,
SEGMENTATION_DATE,
OFFER_ID,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSCRIBER_ID ORDER BY SEGMENTATION_DATE RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED     PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS SENDEVER,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSCRIBER_ID ORDER BY SEGMENTATION_DATE RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 
COUNT(CASE WHEN (OFFER_ID =580169) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSCRIBER_ID ORDER    BY SEGMENTATION_DATE RANGE BETWEEN 180 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS SEND6M580169
FROM myTable
```

PARTITION BY groups the table according to the SUBSCRIBER_ID field and by using proper RANGE BETWEEN statements on each group's rows, I only pick the ones which has the appropriate dates, in the desired time interval.

By using a CASE WHEN statement on the OFFER_ID field, I further filter the rows in the current SUBSCRIBER_ID group and throw out all rows with the invalid offer id.

The nice thing is there is no self join needed here, reducing the order of the operation a magnitude down.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a self-join like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, NVL2(t2.subscriber_id, 'Yes', 'No') as match_found
FROM
  myTable t1 LEFT JOIN 
  myTable t2 ON t1.subscriber_id = t2.subscriber_id 
              AND t1.date > t2.date AND t2.date >= t1.date - 30
              AND t2.offerid = <filter_offer_id>
```